# Range slider resetting to default on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm making an Etch-a-Sketch with a range slider to change the grid size, but the slider keeps resetting to its default size (16x16) as soon as I move the mouse after changing the value (if I change the value and don't move the mouse, the size doesn't reset). For some reason this doesn't happen on Chrome: the value and grid size both change and stay that way until I change them again.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CamiCoding/7zpt14cs/

HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Etch-a-Sketch</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="btns">
            <button id="blackBtn">Black</button>
            <button id="rainbowBtn">Rainbow</button>
            <button id="colorBtn">Color</button>
            <button id="eraserBtn">Eraser</button>
            <button id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
            <div class="colorPicker">
                <input type="color" id="color" value="#000000">
                <span>Pick a color</span>
            </div>
            <div class="sliderAndValue">
                <input type="range" min="2" max="100" value="16" id="slider">
                <p class="value">16</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
        </div>
        <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  src:  url("../fonts/sf-atarian-system.regular.ttf");
  font-family: Atarian;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Atarian;
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
}

.title h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.btns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 700px;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btns button {
  font-family: Atarian;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.btns button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.btns .active {
  background-color: #505050;
  color: white;
}

.colorPicker {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.color span {
  text-align: center;
}

#color {
  width: 90px;
}

.sliderAndValue {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
  outline: none;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

/* for firefox */
#slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

/* for chrome/safari */
#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell.active {
  background-color: black;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 2fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 2fr);
  border: 5px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 700px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
const resetBtn = document.getElementById('resetBtn');
const eraserBtn = document.getElementById('eraserBtn');
const blackBtn = document.getElementById('blackBtn');
const colorBtn = document.getElementById('colorBtn')
const colorValue = document.getElementById('color');
const slider = document.getElementById('slider');
const sliderValue = document.querySelector('.value');
const DEFAULT_COLOR = '#000000';
const DEFAULT_MODE = 'black';
const DEFAULT_SIZE = 16;

let currentColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
let currentMode = DEFAULT_MODE;
let mouseDown = false

document.body.onmousedown = () => (mouseDown = true)
document.body.onmouseup = () => (mouseDown = false)

function setCurrentColor(newColor) {
    currentColor = newColor;
}

function setCurrentMode(newMode) {
    activateButton(newMode);
    currentMode = newMode;
}

blackBtn.onclick = () => setCurrentMode('black');
rainbowBtn.onclick = () => setCurrentMode('rainbow');
eraserBtn.onclick = () => setCurrentMode('eraser');
colorBtn.onclick = () => setCurrentMode('color');
resetBtn.onclick = () => createGrid();

function createGrid() {
    removeCells(grid);
    let val = document.getElementById('slider').value;
    sliderValue.textContent = val;
    grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = (`repeat(${val}, 2fr`);
    grid.style.gridTemplateRows = (`repeat(${val}, 2fr`);
    for(let i = 0; i < val * val; i++) {
        const cell = document.createElement('div');
        cell.classList.add('cell');
        cell.addEventListener('mouseover', changeColor);
        cell.addEventListener('mousedown', changeColor);
        grid.appendChild(cell);
    }
}

function activateButton(newMode) {
    if (currentMode === 'rainbow') {
        rainbowBtn.classList.remove('active');
    } else if (currentMode === 'color') {
        colorBtn.classList.remove('active');
    } else if (currentMode === 'eraser') {
        eraserBtn.classList.remove('active');
    } else if (currentMode === 'black') {
        blackBtn.classList.remove('active');
    }

    if (newMode === 'rainbow') {
        rainbowBtn.classList.add('active');
    } else if (newMode === 'color') {
        colorBtn.classList.add('active');
    } else if (newMode === 'eraser') {
        eraserBtn.classList.add('active');
    } else if (newMode === 'black') {
        blackBtn.classList.add('active');
    }
}

function changeColor(e) {
    if (e.type === 'mouseover' && !mouseDown) return;
    if (currentMode === 'rainbow') {
        const randomR = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        const randomG = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        const randomB = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${randomR}, ${randomG}, ${randomB})`;
    } else if (currentMode === 'color') {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = colorValue.value;
    } else if (currentMode === 'eraser') {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
    } else if (currentMode === 'black') {
        e.target.style.background = '#000000';
    }
}

slider.addEventListener('input', function(){
    let val = document.getElementById('slider').value;
    sliderValue.textContent = val;
    removeCells(grid);
    grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = (`repeat(${val}, 2fr`);
    grid.style.gridTemplateRows = (`repeat(${val}, 2fr`);
    for (let i = 0; i < val * val; i++) {
        const cell = document.createElement('div');
        cell.classList.add('cell');
        cell.addEventListener('mouseover', changeColor);
        cell.addEventListener('mousedown', changeColor);
        grid.appendChild(cell);
    }
});

function removeCells(parent){
    while(grid.firstChild){
        grid.removeChild(grid.firstChild);
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    createGrid(DEFAULT_SIZE);
    activateButton(DEFAULT_MODE);
}
```

I do have another question regarding this same project, but about a different issue, please let me know if I should post a different question for it or if I should post it here too!

Thanks a lot in advance :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to track down the source of the issue, and fix it. Sounds weird, but `document.body.onmousedown` and `document.body.onmouseup` were creating the issue.
Replacing them with `addEventListener` seems to fix it.

I also removed some repeated code *(in `slider`'s input listener)*, by making maximum use of `createGrid()` function.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
const resetBtn = document.getElementById('resetBtn');
const eraserBtn = document.getElementById('eraserBtn');
const blackBtn = document.getElementById('blackBtn');
const colorBtn = document.getElementById('colorBtn')
const colorValue = document.getElementById('color');
const slider = document.querySelector('#slider');
const sliderValue = document.querySelector('.value');
const DEFAULT_COLOR = '#000000';
const DEFAULT_MODE = 'black';
const DEFAULT_SIZE = 16;

let currentColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
let currentMode = DEFAULT_MODE;
let mouseDown = false

document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", () => (mouseDown = true))
document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", () => (mouseDown = false))

function setCurrentColor(newColor) {
  currentColor = newColor;
}

function setCurrentMode(newMode) {
  activateButton(newMode);
  currentMode = newMode;
}

blackBtn.onclick = () => setCurrentMode('black');
rainbowBtn.onclick = () => setCurrentMode('rainbow');
eraserBtn.onclick = () => setCurrentMode('eraser');
colorBtn.onclick = () => setCurrentMode('color');
resetBtn.onclick = () => createGrid();

function createGrid(val = 16) {
  slider.value = val;
  sliderValue.textContent = val;
  removeCells(grid);
  grid.style.gridTemplateColumns = (`repeat(${val}, 2fr`);
  grid.style.gridTemplateRows = (`repeat(${val}, 2fr`);
  for (let i = 0; i < val * val; i++) {
    const cell = document.createElement('div');
    cell.classList.add('cell');
    cell.addEventListener('mouseover', changeColor);
    cell.addEventListener('mousedown', changeColor);
    grid.appendChild(cell);
  }

}

function activateButton(newMode) {
  if (currentMode === 'rainbow') {
    rainbowBtn.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (currentMode === 'color') {
    colorBtn.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (currentMode === 'eraser') {
    eraserBtn.classList.remove('active');
  } else if (currentMode === 'black') {
    blackBtn.classList.remove('active');
  }

  if (newMode === 'rainbow') {
    rainbowBtn.classList.add('active');
  } else if (newMode === 'color') {
    colorBtn.classList.add('active');
  } else if (newMode === 'eraser') {
    eraserBtn.classList.add('active');
  } else if (newMode === 'black') {
    blackBtn.classList.add('active');
  }
}

function changeColor(e) {
  if (e.type === 'mouseover' && !mouseDown) return;
  if (currentMode === 'rainbow') {
    const randomR = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const randomG = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const randomB = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${randomR}, ${randomG}, ${randomB})`;
  } else if (currentMode === 'color') {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = colorValue.value;
  } else if (currentMode === 'eraser') {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
  } else if (currentMode === 'black') {
    e.target.style.background = '#000000';
  }
}

slider.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  let val = parseInt(document.getElementById('slider').value);
  createGrid(val);
});

function removeCells(parent) {
  while (grid.firstChild) {
    grid.removeChild(grid.firstChild);
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  createGrid(DEFAULT_SIZE);
  activateButton(DEFAULT_MODE);
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  src:  url("../fonts/sf-atarian-system.regular.ttf");
  font-family: Atarian;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Atarian;
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
}

.title h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.btns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 700px;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btns button {
  font-family: Atarian;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.btns button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.btns .active {
  background-color: #505050;
  color: white;
}

.colorPicker {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.color span {
  text-align: center;
}

#color {
  width: 90px;
}

.sliderAndValue {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
  outline: none;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

/* for firefox */
#slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

/* for chrome/safari */
#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell.active {
  background-color: black;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 2fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 2fr);
  border: 5px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 700px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: white;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Etch-a-Sketch</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="btns">
            <button id="blackBtn">Black</button>
            <button id="rainbowBtn">Rainbow</button>
            <button id="colorBtn">Color</button>
            <button id="eraserBtn">Eraser</button>
            <button id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
            <div class="colorPicker">
                <input type="color" id="color" value="#000000">
                <span>Pick a color</span>
            </div>
            <div class="sliderAndValue">
                <input type="range" min="2" value="16" id="slider">
                <p class="value">16</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
        </div>
        <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it! I do have an additional question, if it's not too much bother: sometimes when I'm running the mouse over the grid while holding the LMB, instead of coloring the cells it grabs the whole thing like it's picture, and the paint function gets stuck on "mouseover" until I click the LMB again. Any thoughts on how to prevent that?

Comment: @Camila You can add `user-select: none;` to `.grid`. Please check updated answer

Comment: Have you found a more understandable reason why this bugs exist.I'm using angular and my app when running on firefox keeps having this behaviour of resetting to previous value even when the input element is setted to the new one.My app is complex and I'm not able to reproduce the error.Any clues on how to track the events triggered on firefox for example?Thanks in advance

Comment: finally fixed it by removing an angular method for attaching event and replaced a `window` event listener with `addEventListener`. I guess this is a bug in firefox